# Sampling Process Question

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling

This is what I know about the basic sampling process
[image]

I am told that fbar(t) (i.e the sampled signal) is defined for all t. I don't understand that. If n is a finite integer (..,-3, -2, -1, 0, 1...), then clearly it won't be defined n=1.5. So how is it defined for all t? Also I thought that sampled signals are always discrete and I understand that continious signals are defined for all t, it makes no sense that this is continious.

Comment: $\bar{f}(t)$ is not a discrete-time signal; it's still continuous. However, it is equal to zero for all $t \neq nT$.

Comment: I thought the same thing but say if n=1.5 and since fbar_t is equal to a summation that relies on n=1,2,3, then shouldn't it be undefined for n=1.5? I just don't see how you can use a summation sigma symbol that relies on discrete n values to repersent something continuous.

Comment: @MBaz, Slight correction, it is not continuous although it is defined on the entire domain.

Comment: The delta function is zero when the argument is not zero, not undefined.

Comment: @MBaz, careful with terminology.  $\bar{f}(t)$ **is** a *continuous-time* signal, that is it is a function of continuous $t$, but, unless $f(nT)=0 \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\bar{f}(t)$ is not continuous.

Comment: @AlfroJang80, $f(nT)$ is a sequence that we usually called $f[n]$ or the more anachronistic, $f_n$.  and they're defined only for an argument that is integer $n$.  we call those *"discrete-time functions"*.  but both $f(t)$ and $\bar{f}(t)$ are functions of a continuous-$t$ argument.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, CedronDawg, thanks for keeping me honest. I meant "it is a continuous-time signal", in the sense that it's defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The signal itself is of course not continuous in general.

Comment: Ah perfect. I think I get it now. Thank you all!!

Comment: Is it possible to have a discrete signal in general but also be a continious-time signal in that its defined for all t element of real numbers. Like in this case fbar(t) is not defined everywhere - making it discrete but it is continious for every real t. Is there such thing as continious in time discrete signal?